# what is the orange star on yellow file folder icon in windows7 File Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

The yellow folder on my thumb drive at S:\BACKUP\Favorites\
has an orange star outline on it.

The other folders do not.

Comment: That's just the icon the "Favorites" folder gets. It is the exact same if you went to your home folder and looked at your Favorites. Just like the Downloads folder has a little downward arrow in it's icon.

Answer (score 5):

Well, star, especially the yellow star, is a "universal" symbol for favorites, or bookmarks in web browsing context

You can meet the phenomenon in various web browsers and in your User (or Home, especially named such in Linux operating systems, located at path specified in `%userprofile%` variable in Windows) folder which looks just like that in folders being roughly an Windows Explorer, that is a file manager feature:

[image]

And like that as Internet Explorer's, that is a browser feature

[image]

Further, you can put the icon on any folder in Windows by changing its Properties

[image]

Which is contained inside `SHELL32.dll` dynamic library file as seen in the image

[image]

Where `%SystemRoot%` is the Windows' directory, usually, `C:\Windows` folder

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a hidden file in the folder called `desktop.ini` which specifies special names and icons for folders.  This causes some confusion in scenarios like yours where you're moving the folder and don't expect this "special" status to follow it.

*(Another common example is your `My Documents` folder.  In Explorer it shows up as `My Documents`.  However, the action folder is named `Documents`)*

---

If you want to see/delete the `desktop.ini` file you can [change your Explorer settings to **not hide** protected operating system files](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/).

(The option that needs to be **unchecked** is at the bottom of the image below - `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)`)

[image]